# CSS 3.0 Valid Color Property

Tags: css, visual-studio, w3c, w3c-validation

Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) states (with a red squiggly) that

> rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) is not a valid color property value

But the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) says it is. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure you are validating the css for version 3.0 only.
You can see it by going to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> Validation`

Comment: I don't trust a validator that calls it CSS 3.0 (with the ".0")...

Comment: Not entirely sure why my comment was flagged as not constructive - the validator that comes with Visual Studio is extremely out of date, not to mention it doesn't even refer to the technology correctly in its claim of supporting it. That's why I said I wouldn't trust such a validator.

Answer (score 5):

It is valid. Visual Studio doesn't have the greatest validation for HTML5/CSS3 features.

[CSS Tricks - RGBa](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Comment: For anybody looking at the question's tags... neither does the W3C Jigsaw validator for that matter. The best validator these days is manual reference of current specifications.

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid color property as per CSS3 standards;

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)
```

The fourth parameter `0.4` refers to the opacity which is a CSS3 feature, and `a` in `rgba` means `alpha`

You could also try this in Visual Studio to see that it doesn't flag an error;

```
rgb(255, 255, 255);
```